# How to make this nested select query?

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

how can I make this work?

```
$current_id=5;
SELECT Id FROM table1 WHERE Output='yes' and Time>(SELECT Time FROM table2 WHERE Id="'.$current_id.'") ORDER BY Time
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know, it doesnt select something and I'm sure it should do that.

Comment: what is your expected result, what is your data structure? provide some information so anyone can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that $current_id actually has a value. Then check whether the subquery returns a value.

The query itself looks proper